# Visual Studio Opens Blank Browser Page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I got a new laptop for work and installed visual studio 2017 Professional version 15.9.39

But when I try to debug any of our web projects it just opens a blank webpage. If I enter "localhost://XXXXX" where XXXXX is my portnumber then it opens the webpage and I can continue to debug.

I have tried various different browsers and they all work the same way - blank web page but I can enter  url and then it seems to connect.

I have also installed VS2019 professional and that works the same way. Why is it not opening to the localhost url with specified port?

Comment: Look at the Web project's properties and go to the Web tab. Go to the middle of the page, and you will see a "Servers" area. Check the settings here and make sure the project url and those settings are correct, and play around with them until you get it working (maybe you need to select IIS Express in the option). https://imgur.com/RXWrGGz

Comment: just try hitting the  create new virtual folder (nothing else) in the project web tab. See if that works.

Comment: changing the start option to "current page" resolved the issue

Comment: @HanletEscaño "Play around with them until you get it working" is doing a lot of lifting in that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, the solution is that changing the start option to "current page".